# Vertical bar in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, telnet

I'm dealing with inherited shell scripts, and have encountered a syntax I've never seen before.

```
host = 192.[mask]
port = 2[mask]

( echo open ${host} ${port}
    ...about six other commands
  echo exit ) | telnet
```

Now, this makes sense up to the vertical bar. Just commands to open and run commands on a server.

But what's the `telnet` call actually doing? What does this syntax (of parens and bar) mean? My best guess from this implies that it opens telnet, then runs the following commands from within telnet, but I'd like to be sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parentheses are there to group the output of all the commands that are inside them into one Unix [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) `|` which goes to the input of the `telnet` command.

But the parentheses create a subshell and you don't need any, so you can do:

```
{
    telnet_input_line_1
    telnet_input_line_2
    telnet_input_line_3
    (...)
} | telnet
```

You can even replace `telnet` by `netcat`; it's better designed for scripting purposes.

Comment: +1: In this context, there's a sub-shell whether you use `{ ... }` or `( ... )` because of the pipe.  In many ways, the biggest difference is syntactic; the `}` of an I/O redirection must appear where a command could appear, after a semi-colon or a newline, usually.  The `)` of a sub-shell is less restricted.

Answer (score 5):

The `|` is a "pipe", which effectively types the "open ..." text into `telnet`.  Where `telnet` would normally read input from the keyboard, instead it reads it from the preceding command.

The parentheses group together the commands so that all their output goes to `telnet`.